# segmentation fault with reading from directory

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read from 2 directories and place their contents into two dynamic arrays 
when i read i am getting a seg fault. the only place i could see it would be in the loop to add?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  // get directory parameters



  DIR *dirA;
  DIR *dirB;
  struct dirent *dA;
  struct dirent *dB;

  //check if dir A exists
  if (!(dirA = opendir(argv[1])))
    fprintf(stderr,"Failed to open directory %s \n",argv[1]);
  //check if dir B exists
  if (!(dirB = opendir(argv[2])))
    fprintf(stderr,"Failed to open directory %s \n",argv[2]);
  //open dir
  dirA= opendir(argv[1]);
  dirB= opendir(argv[2]);
  int sizeA;
  int sizeB;

  while (0!= (dA = readdir(dirA)))
   {

      sizeA++;

    }

  while (0!= (dB = readdir(dirB)))
    {
      sizeB++;
    }
  char**contentsA;
  char**contentsB;
  contentsA=(char**)(malloc(80*sizeof(char*)));
  contentsB=(char**)(malloc(80*sizeof(char*)));
  int i=0;
  while (0!= (dA = readdir(dirA)))
    {
     contentsA[i]=dA->d_name;
      i++;
    }
  i=0;
     while (0!= (dB = readdir(dirB)))
   {
     contentsB[i]=dB->d_name;
   }
     for ( i=0; i<sizeA; i++)
{

  printf("%s\n", contentsA[i]);
}

  for ( i=0; i<sizeB; i++)
{

  printf("%s\n", contentsB[i]);
}
  printf("size a = %d \n size b = %d\n", sizeA, sizeB);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

i think the problem might be in the last loop

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? If you do, it will stop when the crash happens, and let you examine the function call stack as well as values of variables.

Comment: Oh, and I can see three (alternatively four, depending how you see it) clear possible cases of *undefined behavior* which may indeed lead to crashes.

Comment: You're leaking directory pointers because you open each directory twice, throwing away the first pointer.

Comment: i used gdb and found the problem was in the second loop it was not reading the directory contents into the arry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors.

One is that you're storing the name pointers from directory entries, but not copying the string data. You're just copying the pointer, which points to memory you don't own. It's highly likely that all of the names point to the same location in memory.

Further, you never use the count of items in each directory, but instead hardcode 80 entries. If there are more than 80 you will overwrite random memory.

You should also close the directory and re-open it, or (better) call [`rewinddir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rewinddir) before looping the second time, otherwise your directory stream is exhausted.

Comment: I tried using sizeA to set the size of the array, but when I used my while loop the second time it was already starting at the end. I am very new to unix io, and C in general, it there a way that i could start at the beging of the directory. my goal is to use the array comapring the two directories to merge and remove duplicates so wouldent a pointer to the memory be what i want, if not what would you recommend